# New/Edit functionality in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, popup, edit

Have landed into a scenario.

I have a user control in which I have few images. First image helps me to open a pop-up(different aspx page). I do some operations and save some stuffs to the DB, it has few textboxes and list views etc. This works pretty fine.
I need to implement the Edit functionality to the same popup. I haven't done this kinda thing earlier, hence don't have much idea on it. Googling din't too help much.
How should I go ahead and implement the Edit functionality.

I need to open the same pop up with the textboxes and listviews loaded with values from DB and need to edit that. 
I am dilemmic as to how to start on this.

Pointers will be highly appreciated.
Regards
Anurag

Comment: You can reuse the UI. Just need to hide the "Add New" button and populate textboxes with values fetched from db. And of course show the "Edit" button.

But to me it is simpler just create a new UI for edit and separate code for New and Edit.

Comment: thanks for the comment..anyways I got an idea as to how to initiate this..I am calling the same popup using a quesry string, which will tell me that now Edit operation's gonna be performed..